# Get only all the visible text from a url

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, plaintext

I want to get all the visible text from a url. I need to clear all html code and get plain text.

The process does not have to be perfect, but I would like the text to be as clean as possible.

Do you know any way to make it relatively simple?

Thanks!
Javi.

Comment: What are you asking for here? Please edit and make your answer clear and show examples of what you're wanting to make your question clear.

Comment: @Martin *Please edit and make your **answer** clear and show examples of* answer? ;-)

Comment: @Andreas I was not in the review system I stumbled upon it in the PHP tag doing my daily rounds and this is not an Answer it's a Question :P

Comment: I don't understand what you want. I think the question is clear. In fact, I got a valid answer to the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string
```

It may do the job.

Comment: Oh, thank you. It's perfect. I am self-taught and do not know all the functions of php... strip_tags will make the action.

Answer (score 0):

You can get url the value of the query string using `$_GET['the names in there']`. and use `strip_tags` to get only the text.

```
function get_url(){ return $_GET['name userd'];}
```

and use something like this